# JavaScript select radio on clicking of textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a JavaScript code. There are two radio buttons, with one has text area.

When click on text area the same radio button is to be selected.

```
Message: <input type="radio" style="float:left;" name="rdScriptChoice" value="now" />
<textarea name="txtVdoScript" id="word_count" cols="1" rows="1"> </textarea><br />
<input type="radio" name="rdScriptChoice" value="later" />I will message Later.
```

Here is the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/J2NHW/

Comment: I see no question here. You need to ask a clear and detailed question about a specific problem. If there is a problem with your code, you need to provide a fully functional yet minimal example of the problem directly in your question instead of linking to some other site.

Comment: `I am trying to build a JavaScript code` Ok, go ahead and start! Once you've tried something, and run into an issue, head on back!

Comment: So where is the question?

Comment: @cookiemonster besides giving lecture, if you'd have provided a solution as imbondbaby gave, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I've modified your code here:- http://jsfiddle.net/J2NHW/2/

Comment: @user3788309: Stop crying and realize that StackOverflow has criteria for questions posted. This isn't a code writing service, and your posts are no exception.

Comment: @Indra why it is not working on my webpage? I used the code in a separate js file

Comment: I've made a small modification, http://jsfiddle.net/J2NHW/5/ . It should work now. And if even it doesn't work then I think you have not linked your javascript file or the jquery library file with your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using JQuery:

Give the first radio button an ID for example: `id="message"`

```
$("#word_count").focus(function(){
  $("#message").prop("checked", true)
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J2NHW/1/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. You truly are awesome. You take the right step. All else gave lectures not solution.

Comment: I mean on my page. Do I have to use something like, $(document).ready(function()
{

Comment: yes, make sure you are importing jquery onto your website

Answer (score 0):

If you know the basics of javaScript just try this way. Get the dom elements using their **ID**'s and manipulate them when **onclick** event of textarea is fired.

**HTML :**

```
Message: <input type="radio" style="float:left;" id="msgRadio" name="rdScriptChoice"     value="now" />
<textarea name="txtVdoScript" id="word_count" cols="1" rows="1"> </textarea><br />
<input type="radio" name="rdScriptChoice" value="later" />I will message Later.
```

**javaScript :**

```
var messageRadioButton = document.getElementById('msgRadio');

var textArea = document.getElementById('word_count');

textArea.onclick = function(){
    messageRadioButton.checked = true;
};
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/2gQYq/)